# error de NPM a la hora de crear un archivo de react: npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, npm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]no puedo crear un archivo nuevo de react debido a este error:
npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE
npm ERR! error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-11-09T17_21_50_845Z-debug.log

he probado varias cosas como actualizar el registro, volver a instalar la version de node, sin exito.

Comment: Hola Luis, por favor menciona que haz intentado ya para que la comunidad tenga más información al respecto

Comment: Hola! pues he intentado desinstalar la version de node , vover a instalarla, actualizar el registro de node, reiniciar el pc, desinstalar visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

Buscando varias soluciones en Internet probé algunas de estas:

- Prueba npm installcon otro repositorio
- Intente instalar otra versión de node.js
- npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

Si el método anterior aún falla. Puedes probar estos:

- Desinstale nodejs de Programas y características con el desinstalador.
- Elimina estos archivos:

  - C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs*
  - C:\Program Files\Nodejs*
  - C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm*
  - C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache*
  - C:\Users{User}.npmrc(y posiblemente verifique eso sin el .prefijo también)*

Reiniciar, por si acaso
Intente también instalar node.js nuevamente
Prueba también `npm install` al repositorio de destino

Esta información fue encontrada en este [sitio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194920/cant-install-express-because-npm-install-express-error)